# Condition Variable with Mutex lock demonstration program hangs

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

Idea:

When the thread A needs to check the state of the condition variable `x`, it will first hold the mutex lock then check the variable's state, if found invalid, it will start waiting.

There will be no interruptions from the thread B since thread A currently has the mutex. Once thread A waits, then it will release the mutex.
thread B can then acquire the mutex and do whatever the hell it wishes to.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

pthread_mutex_t mutexLock  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond       = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void *                functionOfThreadA (void * ptr);
void *                functionOfThreadB (void * ptr);
int                     x  = 0;

int main ()
{
    pthread_t threadA;
    pthread_t threadB;
    char      *messageA = (char *) "Thread A"; // TODO
    char      *messageB = (char *) "Thread B";
    int       returnValueA;
    int       returnValueB;


    returnValueA = pthread_create (&threadA, NULL, functionOfThreadA, (void*) messageA);
    returnValueB = pthread_create (&threadB, NULL, functionOfThreadB, (void*) messageB);

    pthread_join (threadA, NULL);
    pthread_join (threadB, NULL);

    exit (0);
}

void * functionOfThreadA (void * ptr)
{
    char * message;
    message = (char *) ptr;
    std :: cout << "\nA: " << message << "\n";

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexLock);

        if (x == 10)
        {
            std :: cout << "\nx == 10 : true, functionOfThread A: " << message << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std :: cout << "\nThread waits." << "\n";
            pthread_cond_wait (&cond, &mutexLock);
            std :: cout << "\nA:++ " << message << "\n";
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexLock);
        return 0;
    }
}

void * functionOfThreadB (void * ptr)
{
    while (1)
    {
        char * message;
        message = (char *) ptr;

        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexLock);

        x = x + 1;
        if (x == 10)
        {
            std :: cout << "\nfunctionOfThread B: " << message << "\n";
            pthread_cond_signal (&cond);
        }
        else
        {
            std :: cout << "\nB: Not signaled yet. Value of x: " << x << "\n";
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexLock);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
anisha@linux-trra:~> ./a.out 
B: Not signaled yet. Value of x: 1

A: Thread A

Thread waits.
^C
```

And then it simply hangs.

**What do I need to correct here and why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been discovered.

After issuing the signal, I need to get out of the loop. But before I do so, I also need to unlock the mutex. The added code in `functionOfThreadB` has been highlighted by the ************** in the program below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

pthread_mutex_t mutexLock  = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  cond       = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void *                functionOfThreadA (void * ptr);
void *                functionOfThreadB (void * ptr);
int                     x  = 0;

int main ()
{
    pthread_t threadA;
    pthread_t threadB;
    char      *messageA = (char *) "Thread A";
    char      *messageB = (char *) "Thread B";
    int       returnValueA;
    int       returnValueB;

    returnValueA = pthread_create (&threadA, NULL, functionOfThreadA, (void*) messageA);
    returnValueB = pthread_create (&threadB, NULL, functionOfThreadB, (void*) messageB);

    pthread_join (threadA, NULL);
    pthread_join (threadB, NULL);

    exit (0);
}

void * functionOfThreadA (void * ptr)
{
    char * message;
    message = (char *) ptr;

    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexLock);

        if (x == 1000)
        {
            std :: cout << "\nA: x is now 1000. Waiting period over."<< "\n";
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            std :: cout << "\nNow, thread A will wait for value of `x` to reach 1000" << "\n";
            pthread_cond_wait (&cond, &mutexLock);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexLock);
    }
}

void * functionOfThreadB (void * ptr)
{
    while (1)
    {
        char * message;
        message = (char *) ptr;

        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexLock);

        x = x + 1;
        if (x == 1000)
        {
            std :: cout << "\nB: Signaled. Value of x: " << x << "\n";
            pthread_cond_signal (&cond);
    *************pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexLock);*************
    *************return 0;*************
        }
        else
        {
            std :: cout << "\nB: Not signaled yet. Value of x: " << x << "\n";
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexLock);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need an infinite loop in Thread A: You can simply have `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock); while (x != 1000) pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutexLock); phtread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock);`

Answer (score 1):

Thread waits here  `pthread_cond_wait (&cond, &mutexLock);` indifinitely because there is no other thread which signals it. Thread B does nothing with the lock and the condition variable

Comment: Oh, I haven't sent a signal? :doh: That's the problem?

Comment: change x = x + 1; to x = 10; This satisfies the given sample code because each thread loops only once. For general case let me think.

Comment: I am prividing you a working solution. Please check it. If it solves your problem let me know.

Comment: `each thread loops only once.` But I have written an infinite while loop there. Then why?

Comment: Because there is `return 0` at the end of the loop